# Find and move word in string to the end of the sentence. Python3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

**Input:**  'blah move_me2 , nah '

**Output:** 'blah  , nah  move_me2'

**Current code:**

```
raw = 'blah move_me2 , nah '
word = 'move_me'
start_idx = raw.index('move_me')
end_idx = ed_idx + len(word) + 1
raw = raw + ' ' + raw[start_idx:end_idx]
raw = raw.replace(raw[start_idx:end_idx], '', 1)
print(raw)
```

**Need help with:** Is it possible to make it more efficient and possibly with regex?

Note: "move_me" word may have few extra charters at the end, in this case '2'

Comment: yes, but to use a regex there would need to be a pattern

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you. I didn't know about the Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 're' module to get the expected string.

```
import re

raw = 'blah move_me2 , nah '
word = 'move_me'
find_str = re.search(r'(%s[^\s]+)' % word, raw)
if find_str:
    new_str = raw[find_str.span()[0]:find_str.span()[1]:]
    renew_str = raw.replace(new_str, '')
    renew_str += new_str
    print(renew_str)
```

**Output:**

```
blah  , nah move_me2
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. However "move_me" word may have few extra charters at the end, in this case, '2'. Is it possible to move it all together with 'extra charters' at the end?

Comment: @Good_Man I have edited the old code. Please review the new code. It may help you.

Comment: `[^\s]` is same as `\S`

Answer (score 1):

This code works, I dont know if it fits your wishes, cause it just uses plain python string opeartors instead of regex. You can find and replace a string and then append it. At the moment there is no check wheter the string actually is in raw. Maybe you should proove that first.

```py
raw = 'blah move_me2 , nah '
word = 'move_me'
a = raw.replace(word, "") + str(word)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
blah 2 , nah move_me
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you almost answered my question. The only issue the "move_me" word may have few extra charters at the end, in this case '2'.

Comment: For me the code works if I change "word" to `word = 'move_me2'`...

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what would be at the end of the "move_me". Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood what you want the following code may help you :

```
raw_input = 'blah move_me2 , nah ' 
word = 'move_me'
pos_start = raw_input.find(word)
raw_output = raw_input[:pos_start] + raw_input[pos_start+len(word):] + word
print(raw_output)
```

The find function is a good way to find the position of a something in a string (it returns the starting position of the word/sentence).

I made a shorter version of this if you want :

```
raw_input,word = 'blah move_me2 , nah ','move_me'
raw_output = raw_input[:raw_input.find(word)] + raw_input[raw_input.find(word)+len(word):] + word
print(raw_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the span function work on the output of the search to slice the original string, pluck out the word, and paste it at the end of the string.

```
import re
txt="blah move_me2 , nah "
txt[:re.search("move_me2",txt).span()[0]] + txt[re.search("move_me2",txt).span()[1]:]+" move_me2"
```